# Typescript cannot find module defined in paths

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript application that has `paths` for absolute imports. My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "utils*": ["src/utils*"],
        "operations*": ["src/operations*"],
        "actions*": ["src/actions*"],
        "components*": ["src/components*"],
        "constants*": ["src/constants*"],
      },
      "outDir": "dist",
      "module": "esnext",
      "target": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noEmit": true,
      "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "strict": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "dist",
    ],
    "include": [
      "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "files": [
      "./typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
  }
```

and I'm trying to use imports like so:

```
import { AppStateType } from 'actions/app';
```

however I get `cannot find module 'actions/app'`

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44677624/4126418) answer but it didn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for `paths` is kind of picky.

Try this:

```
"paths": {
    "utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
    "operations/*": ["src/operations/*"],
    "actions/*": ["src/actions/*"],
    "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
    "constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
},
```

Note the addition of a slash.

Since you have `baseUrl` set I think that should work, but if not the next step might be to specify the full relative path (relative to the `tsconfig` file):

```
"paths": {
    "utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"],
    "operations/*": ["./src/operations/*"],
    "actions/*": ["./src/actions/*"],
    "components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
    "constants/*": ["./src/constants/*"],
},
```

That will satisfy the TypeScript compiler, but if you're using Webpack or Parcel you may get complaints about them not being able to find the files even though TypeScript compiles it fine. In that case you need to set aliases for your bundler. It would look a bit like this:

[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

```
// webpack.config.js or similar
// ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"], // import without .js, .jsx, .json extensions
    alias: {
      "utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utils/*"),
      "operations": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/operations/*"),
      "actions": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/actions/*"),
      "components": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/*"),
      "constants": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/constants/*")
    }
  },
```

[Parcel](https://parceljs.org/module_resolution.html)

```
// package.json
// ...
  "alias": {
    "utils": "./src/utils/*",
    "operations": "./src/operations/*",
    "actions": "./src/actions/*",
    "components": "./src/components/*",
    "constants": "./src/constants/*"
  }
```